# Why do MathML identifiers look different?

Tags: html, fonts, mathml

The letters in a MathML `<mi>` tag look different (only if it's a single letter in the `<mi>`):

```html
<div> abc </div>
<math> <mi>a</mi> <mi>b</mi> <mi>c</mi> <mi>abc</mi> </math>
```

how does this happen? I tested that it's different with different fonts, is this a special mode of the font? Can I activate it without MathML?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element/mi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

From the documentation for the [`<mi>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element/mi):

> By default `<mi>` elements that contain multiple characters are a rendered as normal text, while single character characters are rendered as italic: the same formatting behavior as the CSS `text-transform` property with a value of `math-auto`. The `mathvariant` attribute with a value of `normal` can be used to reset a single character to the normal font.

It's just the italic face of the font. To activate it without MathML, you could style text using CSS with `font-style: italic;`

Comment: I can't see it with the font used in examples here, but I'm testing it with Latin Modern Math, and it doesn't look the same with just italics - the shape of the letter in `<mi>` is different. Is there anything else that it does?

Comment: The `<mi>` element, as per its name, is the "mathematical identifier", and uses the Mathematical alphanumerics Unicode characters (specifically, the "Italics" subset). So even though you "wrote" a normal letter in `<mi>a</mi>`, MathML parsing will replace that "a" (U+0061) with "" (U+1D44E). And since those aren't really meant to typeset actual text, if you specify more than one "letter" inside <mi>, the MathML parser won't rewrite anything, because text needs to be typeset by the text engine, which it can't do unless it's real text.